# How to set multiple UISwitches ON which are created in loop programmatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, uiswitch

I have done following code for creating multiple UISwitches programmatically and handle particular switch.

```
for (int i =0; i < 3; i++) {

    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(x, y, height, width);
    UISwitch *switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:frame];

    //add tag as index 
    switchControl.tag = i;
    [switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(flip:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];

    [switchControl setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:switchControl];

    y= y+50.0;
}

- (IBAction) flip: (id) sender {
    UISwitch *onoff = (UISwitch *) sender;
    NSLog(@"no.%d %@",onoff.tag, onoff.on ? @"On" : @"Off");
    //use onoff.tag , you know which switch you got 
}
```

After doing this code I want set all UISwitches ON when UIButton select all clicked. How?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set them all `ON` I'd save them in an array for easier access. Then you could do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < [switchArray count]; i++) {
  UISwitch *sw = (UISwitch *)[switchArray objectAtIndex:i];
  [sw setOn:YES];
}
```

You can also do it like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  UISwitch *sw = (UISwitch *)[self.view viewWithTag:i];
  [sw setOn:YES];
}
```

Just make sure that tags are unique.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Please can you tell me how i can make switchArray here. I tried but it giving error expression not assignable. I am new in iPhone.so may be my question is simple.

Comment: @python declare an array before your `for-loop`. Then in the loop add that switch to the array. I'd use an `NSMutableArray` for that. In the header: `NSMutableArray *switchArray;`, then in the implementation file before the for-loop: `switchArray = [NSMutableArray array];` and at the end of the loop(but still IN the loop): `[switchArray addObject:switchControl];`. Hope it helps

Comment: I have one more doubt in this. How i can check swicth position in other methods. It needs IBOutlet. How i can create IBOutlet pragmatically in loop? please if u know help me.

Comment: @python to check if it's `ON` or `OFF` use `isOn` method of `UISwitch`. Example: `if ([sw isOn]) { //doSmth} else {//doSmthElse}`

Answer (score 0):

use this thing there
please start tag number with 100s or 1000s

```
-(void) selectAll {
for(int i=100;i<(100+3);i++){
UISwitch *refSwitch=[self.view viewWithTag:i];
refSwitch.on=YES;
}
}
```

this will work for you